# getting the div which handles the post of my categories in wp jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a wp_list_categories which displays my categories of wordpress site. Now I manage to display the post of my wordpress categories from the wp_list_categories by enabling the user to onClick which category will be displayed by not reloading/refreshing the page. I have the code but i cannot get the specific div which contains my post, where it returns my wholepage to be displayed. The output of my code is the ajax/jquery returns the wholepage and put it inside my `div id="inside"`. I want only to get the part of `div id = "inside"` which there is the post from the onclick category selected.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:true});
    var $mainCategory = $('#inside'),
    $cat_links = $('ul.categories-filters li a');

    $cat_links.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $el = $(this);
        var value = $el.attr("href");
        $mainCategory.animate({opacity: "0.5"});
           $mainCategory.load(value + "#inside", function() {
            $mainCategory.animate({opacity: "1"});
    });
    });
});
```

my wp_list_categories and inside the div `id="#inside"` where the posts are there to be displayed.

```
<ul class="categories-filters">
                    <?php 
                        $args2 = array(
                            'exclude'  => array( 6,7,9 ),
                            'order' =>  'DESC',
                            'title_li'  => __(''),
                        );
                    wp_list_categories($args2);
                    ?>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div id="main-category" class="row row-left">
                    <?php if(have_posts()) : 
                        $count = 0;
                        while(have_posts()) : the_post();   ?>

                        <div div id="inside" class="col-xs-3 col-box2">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
                        </div>
                            <?php if($count==2) :
                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '<div class="row row-left">';
                            endif; 
                            $count++; endwhile; 
                        endif; 
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        ?> 
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: `<div div id="inside"` typo?

Comment: perhaps you need to `value + " #inside"` - note the space before `#` - see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you for your answer sir. what do you mean sir ?

Comment: I have not posted an answer, I posted a comment regarding your div having an invalid attribute called div - and then a second one regarding how you are misusing `jQuery.load`

Comment: @JaromandaX here sir i got this  $mainCategory.load(value + "#inside", function() {
            $mainCategory.animate({opacity: "1"});

Comment: if you are trying to get partial page using .load, you are doing it wrong, you need a SPACE before the identifier - which is what I said before and suggested you rad the documentation

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah sir. lol thanks very much you helped me. I got it sir. thank you

Comment: @JaromandaX problem already solved. lol. sir can you answer in my post or i will delete this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with how you use the jquery .load function

```
$mainCategory.load(value + "#inside", function() {
```

the documentation states that there needs to be a space between the URL and the "selector" to partially load the retrieved html

so, it's simply

```
$mainCategory.load(value + " #inside", function() {
```